# php doesn't read the cookie

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

in my php file i have this..

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['test']) ){
    setcookie("test", "testesttest", time()+3600*24*80);
}

    ob_start();
    echo 'autotrackphpre';
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    header("Location: $url");
ob_flush();
```

it's a redirect when you call the php file..
if you call it first it set the cookie..

But the second time it loads.. the cookie get updated...
that is what i don't want.

If the cookie exists then do nothing.

Gr.

Comment: `if (!isset())` then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['test']) ){
    setcookie("test", "testesttest", time()+3600*24*80);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sets the cookie only if it's already set, you probably wanted:

```
!isset($_COOKIE['test'])
```

Comment: @Hanky thanks, I always forget that set is irregular.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is exactly opposite to what it should be. You are setting cookie if the cookie has already been set. This will make the php to update the cookie. Use this code as below

```
if ( !isset($_COOKIE['test']) ){
    setcookie("test", "testesttest", time()+3600*24*80);
}
```

Hope this helps you